# jQuery: Find all p tags in epubjs structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, epub.js

I'm trying to find all the p tags generated by drawing an epub using epubjs.

Here's the structure that I find, all elements described here have a lot of classes and things I can play around with:

```
<div id="container>
  <div id="epubjs-viewer:random-hash">
    <iframe id="epubjs-iframe:random-hash">
        <!-- body of iframe, has some sections with a few <p>'s inside -->
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to access and even modify those contents? I've tried numerous selectors but couldn't get something working.

***Update***

You can get a better idea of the structure here: http://prntscr.com/i7wr9l

Comment: Where does your `<iframe>` point to? Is it on the same domain?

Comment: @ObsidianAge It does not have a `src` so I guess yes? I've added a screenshot in the question details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In epubjs 0.3 you can do it this way:

```
let book = new ePub.Book(bookPath);
let rendition = new Rendition(book, layoutSettings);
rendition.hooks.content.register((content, rendition) => {
    let pElements = content.document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    //...
});
```